# Have a big array of integers need to return an array that has 1 added to the value represented by the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

It is for a studying purpose. Have a big array of integers need to return an array that has 1 added to the value represented by the array.

Tried to convert the array into an integer, but after using 
parseInt('9223372036854775807', 10) received 9223372036854776000, instead of 9223372036854775807
What is going wrong here?

```
var arr = [ 9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 0, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 8, 0, 7 ];

function upArray(arr){

  var numb = arr.join('');
  numb = parseInt(numb, 10);

  var result = numb + 1;

  console.log(result);
  result = result.toString(10).split('').map(Number);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Answer (score 0):

it means the maximum range for an Intiger number has reached, here is a link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

to solve this split the array value and add one to it and then combine then back and display the entire array as a String (don't parse it).

```
    function upArray(arr){
var temp = arr;
var len = arr.length;
var temp2 = arr;
temp2 = temp2.slice(0,len/2).join('');
temp2 = parseInt(temp2);
temp = temp.slice(len/2).join('');
    numb = parseInt(temp) +1;
    if(numb.toString().length > (len/2 + len%2))
{
numb = numb.toString().slice(1);
temp2++;
}

    var result = temp2.toString() + numb.toString();
    console.log(result);
    result = result.split('').map(Number);
    return result;
    }
```

hope it helps and have pass through every test...

Comment: `upArray([1,9])` should be `20` not `110`

Comment: @Andreas i did not get you

Comment: Call your function with `[1,9]`. The result should be `20`.

Comment: `[9,9]` should be `100`

Comment: thanks i noticed that now ,seems like i was adding one to any number even if it could be 9, add also the `toString` part was repetitive removed that as well. XD

Comment: `arr`, `temp` and `temp2` all point on the same array. There's no `.slpice()` method, and this still doesn't work with arbitrary long arrays. PLEASE test your answer before posting...

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeding  the capacity of JavaScript's number type

IEEE-754 double-precision floating point (the kind of number JavaScript uses) can't precisely represent all numbers

Beyond Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1 (9007199254740992), the IEEE-754 floating-point format can no longer represent every consecutive integer

also you dont need to use a second argument to parseInt unless you are looking to use a different base than decimal

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

If you use the code with an array of numbers that when joined is within this limit your code will work

```js
var arr = [ 9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 0, 3, 6, 8, 5 ];
function upArray(arr){

    var numb = arr.join('');
    numb = parseInt(numb);
    var result = numb + 1;
    console.log(result)
    result = result.toString(10).split('').map(Number);
    return result;
}

console.log(upArray(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're exceeding the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.

If you just want to display you can go this way

```js
var arr = [ 9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 0, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 8, 0, 7 ];


function addone(arr){
let carry = 0;
  for(let i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  if(i === arr.length-1) {
    if( arr[i]+1 > 9){
      arr[i] = 10-(arr[i] + 1);
      carry = 1;
    } else {
      arr[i] +=1;
      carry= 0;
    }
  }
  if( i !== arr.length-1 ){
    if( carry === 0) break;
    if( arr[i]+1+carry > 9){
      arr[i] = 10-(arr[i] + carry);
      carry = 1;
    } else {
      arr[i] +=carry;
      carry= 0;
    }
  }
}
if(carry === 1)
arr.unshift(1)
return arr;
}

console.log(addone(arr).join(''))
console.log(addone([1,2,9]).join(''))
console.log(addone([9,9,9]).join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is going beyond the max number value.

Here is recursive appproch for the problem:

```
function upArray(arr, lastIndex){

  if(lastIndex == undefined){
    lastIndex = arr.length - 1;    
  }

  if(lastIndex < 0){
    return;
  }

  if(arr[lastIndex] == 9){
   arr[lastIndex] = 0;     
   upArray(arr, lastIndex - 1);   
 }
  else {   
    arr[lastIndex] = arr[lastIndex] + 1;    
  }  
  return arr; 
}

var arr = [ 9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 0, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 8, 0, 9];
var result = upArray(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution so you can choice =)

```
var arr = [9,9,9];//[ 9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 0, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 8, 0, 7 ];

var i = arr.length;
var append = true;
while(append){
    if(--i < 0){
        arr.unshift(1);
        break;
    }

    var v = arr[i];

    if(++v >= 10)
        v -= 10;
    else
        append = false;

    arr[i] = v;
}

var r = arr.join('');
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

As everybody would agree that the issue here is having a value that is exceeding the capacity of JavaScript's `number` type, we can expect that there'll be proposed workarounds like having to split the array into multiple array and work from there.

We can actually solve this on another approach. Since your representation of a number is splitting it into single digits stored as an array, and you want to perform a simple addition on it, we can observe a representation of a simple/elementary addition. The one where we add a value digit by digit from the bottom and make use of the "Carry Over" concept. We can actually do it that way.

It will look somewhat like this (A bit longer code for readability):

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var y = [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9];

var add1 = (arr) => {
  var hasCarryOver = true;

  for (var index = arr.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    if (!hasCarryOver) {
      break;
    }

    if (arr[index] < 9) {
      arr[index] = arr[index] + 1;
      hasCarryOver = false;
    } else {
      arr[index] = 0;
    }
  }

  if (hasCarryOver) {
    arr.unshift(1);
  }

  return arr;
};

x = add1(x);
y = add1(y);
console.log('result x add 1', x);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0]
console.log('result y add 1', y);
// [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```